# Convert MP4 to ISM in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, encoding, mp4, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I need to generate `.ISM` files from `MP4` files that are uploaded to `Azure BLOB storage`. Probably as soon as the user uploads a MP4 file to BLOB storage I should be able to fire up a Azure Function that does the conversion.

Can someone please help me how to do the conversion from MP4 to .ISM.

**Note**: I do not want to use `Azure Media Service`, it is too expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ism file probably won't help you much at all for this situation.

If you are trying to avoid using AMS completely and just do static packaging, you should generate HLS or DASH content directly into storage blobs.  You could do that with FFMPEG or the Shaka Packager tool from existing Mp4 file.  There are lots of OSS solutions out there that can generate static HLS and DASH content if that is your goal.

The .ism file is primarily a feature of AMS - and it provides the information that the Streaming Endpoint (origin server) needs to dynamically packaging on-the-fly from standard MP4 files to MPEG DASH, HLS, Smooth and add on the DRM encryption for Widevine, Fairplay, and Playready.  If you have no need for the multi-format dynamic packaging from MP4, then AMS is probably not the right solution for your needs.

If you can share - what parts are too expensive for you?  The encoding, the streaming endpoint monthly cost for (standard endpoint cost?) or is it the overall egress bandwidth needed to deliver content from Azure (which won't go away with a storage based solution and is normally 90% of the cost of streaming if you have popular stuff.)

If you are trying to avoid encoding costs, you can encode locally or in ffmpeg on a server vm at your own costs, and then upload and stream with AMS - I have a good sample of that here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/Streaming/StreamExistingMp4

Thanks,
John

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do have a few confusion regarding the pricing. I need to encode the video to a form it can be played in Azure Media Player or Shaka Player. Also, I need to implement DRM so the content can't be stolen. When I experimented with AMS for a video less than 1 minute, I was charged >$3. I maybe wrong, can you give me a rough idea what will be an approximate cost to encode a video so I could apply DRM. Let's say the duration of a Video is 60minutes. Please help.

Comment: If your video is 60 minutes in duration and you want to encode it to a full adaptive bitrate set, you should use either a custom preset - to control the exact costs of the output tracks, or use our Content Aware Encoding preset (see samples in the same repo as above in the VideoEncoding folder).  The CAE preset will recommend the best number of output tracks and resolutions for your video. 

There are some pricing examples on the main pricing page here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/

Comment: Pricing Example: You have a video at 1920 x 1080p resolution, 60 minutes in duration, that you need to encode to an MP4 output of the same length, with the video at 1920 x 1080p resolution and one audio track. The effective multiplier would be 2 (for HD) plus 0.25 (for audio), adding up to a multiplier of 2.25. You would be billed for a total of (60 minutes x 2.25) = 135 output minutes. If you used the Media Encoder Standard for this encoding, then your cost would be (135 output minutes x $0.015 / output minute) = $2.025. 
That is just a single output though in that case.

Comment: Adaptive encoding would output multiple tracks. So it is best to use a custom encoding setting to control costs.   The CAE encoder will not be as predictable, since it decides how many tracks to output and bitrates to use based on the source content. We are adding a feature to do constrained CAE (min and max tracks) in the September SDK release.

Comment: Example 2—Joe has a two-hour movie that is at 1920 x 1080 resolution, which he encodes with Media Encoder Standard using the default “H264 Multiple Bitrate 1080p” preset, so that he can stream the movie to iOS and Android devices. The encoding preset produces 3 HD output videos, 5 SD output videos, and 1 audio. The total multiplier for this encoding task would be (3x2 + 5 + 0.25) = 11.25. Total output minutes would therefore be 11.25 x 2 x 60 = 1,350. The total cost would be 1,350 x $0.015/minute = $20.25.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Can you tell me a bit more about DRM pricing. it says 100 certificates for $0.20. Is it 1 view of a video == 1 certificate or is it 1 user who views the video (even many times) == 1 certificate ?

Comment: That is correct, DRM is per license delivered.  So each client requests a license for playback per DRM (Playready, Widevine, etc.)  However, keep in mind that you can set some DRM systems to be persistent licenses, or non-persitent. Meaning that you can cache the license locally and avoid re-requesting it again.  Depends on your business model and DRM license Rules.  You also may not even need DRM at all - make sure you are using it for the right reason.  The alternative is just using AES-128 envelope encryption support that we have. Ask yourself if you really need the output piracy protection